# MySQL server gone away every time I try to import a Drupal database

Tags: php, drupal, mysql

I'm trying to build a dev enviroment in my PC using a existent site. I copied all the data and export the Drupal DB whithout cache* and watchdog tables to make the script tiny. When I try to import the script which have around 12MB I get "MySQL server gone away" error and don't know why or how to fix it. I've tried from phpMyAdmin, from MySQL command line in the server and so on. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Edit mySql config file my.ini and add below 2 line, restart server and check.

```
max_allowed_packet= 64M

wait_timeout= 6000
```

Answer (score 0):

12MB will not create any problem. Kindly restart your computer. After that try to start the mysql.

Kindly update the mysql config file by two lines

```
max_allowed_packet= 64M

wait_timeout= 6000
```

Comment: my.ini? In CentOS? I didn't found that should I create this file? Where?